# FileSystemWatcher for FTP not notifying when a new file is added to folder

Tags: c#, linux, sftp, filesystemwatcher

I am running my program in a windows  Console app, but I have mapped a NFS drive on the network where I download files via SFTP on a Linux box.   When my shellscript brings back files to that folder my apps is not capturing when the files arrive, but if I copy a file from windows or from Linux it works fine.  It is almost like the FileSystemWatcher doesn't work when it comes from a SFTP script.

here is a sample of the code

```
Global.MainPath = Console.ReadLine();
p.path = Global.MainPath;
MonitorDirectory(p.path);
Console.WriteLine("Checking folder " + p.path);
Console.WriteLine(" ");

while (true)
{
    MonitorDirectory(p.path);
    ShowContent(p.path);
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.Write("Enter q to quit: ");
    line = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (line == "q" || line == "quit")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Clear();
    }
}

// and here's the MonitorDirectory & FileSystemWatcher_Created methods

private static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
{
    FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher
    { Path = path };
    fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
    fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += FileSystemWatcher_Renamed;
    fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += FileSystemWatcher_Deleted;
    fileSystemWatcher.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
    fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 }

private static void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Mypath p = new Mypath();
    Console.Clear();
    p.path = Global.MainPath;
    string filePath = p.path + "\\" + e.Name;
    Console.WriteLine("File created: {0}", e.Name);
    SendEmailtoContacts("File Created " + e.Name, filePath + " has been created from the folder");
    ShowContent(p.path);
}
```

Comment: *"but if I copy a file from windows or from Linux it works fine"* – It's unclear where and to you copy the files. Please be specific. Also you mix SFTP and FTP. Those are completely different things. I do not think your question is about your code or `FileSystemWatcher`. It is more about the system that runs the network share. You didn't tell us much about that. What if you open NFS drive in Windows Explorer. Does it detect when the files are added/modified suing your (S)FTP script?

Comment: you should add some error handling to see at least your code works as expected without any errors

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but in addition to the points that @Joey makes below, I'd pull the `FileSystemWatcher` out of that `MonitorDirectory` method (it's currently a local variable) and make it a member of the class (and, like @Joey, I'd skip the `static`-ness)

Answer (score 0):

you reinitialized the system file watcher in every loop.
remove this:

MonitorDirectory(p.path);

from the loop.

btw: I wouldn't use a static method